# Change background color in render

Tags: rendering, color

I am running the latest version of blender I can find (2.82).  I can't change the background of my rendered image (or the one I view for that matter) no matter what I do.  I've read all the previous times this question has been asked, but the answers looks very complicated and worse, the Blender versions used are different than mine with menus and settings in places that I can't find.  I've read the manual and looked at numerous help tutorials.  This can't be that complicated, can it?  Can someone tell me where to change the background color on the render? (I suppose it's too much to hope someone will someday allow me to right click on the background and pull up a color menu.) In the meantime, how is this done?

P.S., if it isn't obvious, I am a complete webtard and new to Blender. I just can't believe how frustratingly difficult it is to change the simplest things in this application. Though it is obvious that Blender is very powerful and the hard work of many contributors, it is completely non-obvious to me.  Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

In Cycles In your World properties change this color to whatever you want but it'll will affect how your objects are lit, if you don't want that just copy this node set up. In Eevee it's the same set up.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It also works basically the same in Blender 3.4